# What is the tolerance of True Position without Datum Callout

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a drawing that has true position called out on many many holes.  However, there are several holes that have true position (boxed dimensions)called out but no datum reference or control box.  They are called out true position relative to another hole that has true position datum control boxes.  How do I put a tolerance on these?  Do I use the datum from the referenced hole?

Comment: Well, do you want the position tolerance relative to the hole they're called out against, or against the system datum?  Typically that sort of dimensioning indicates a set of holes which must be toleranced to each other to allow fitting another part there.

Comment: Can you post a picture/example? I second @CarlWitthoft. One hole would be located/toleranced to main part Datums and the hole would be defined as a datum. The patterned holes should reference the first hole as a datum.

Answer (score -1):

box dimensions we usually work to are a 2 thou tolerance +/_ 0.001 off target dimension, this might help
http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_Dimension_Tolerance_and_Precision.htm

Comment: This is not an answer.